# "How can i fetch or read this data using eloquent in laravel?"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I was trying to make a simple search filter for a rest api on laravel but I always get the status:404

I've searched for examples but I just got how to Read/Fetch by ID

This is my route;

`Route::post('/inmuebles/buscar','InmueblesController@buscador');`

This is my function;

```
public function buscador(Request $request){
    $precio = $request->input('price');
    $tipotran = $request->input('id_transaccion_type');
    $direccion = $request->input('address'); 
    $tipoprop = $request->input('id_property_type');
    $inmuebles = inmueblem::where('price','<=',$precio)
    ->where('id_transaccion_type',$tipotran)
    ->where('address',$direccion)
    ->where('id_property_type',$tipoprop)->get();

    return response()->json($inmuebles);
}
```

I expect to get all the results that match the request.

Comment: dd() your $request to check if they have a value or not also take a look at https://dev.to/mohammadfouladgar/making-the-advanced-search-query-with-eloquent-builder-in-laravel-30g3

Comment: if you getting a 404 error then it is not getting to your controller function i.e. there s something wrong in your route or UR as it cannot find the URL. If I recall you will get a 422 if the method doesnt match the METHOD i.e. POST so in your case you are not getting past routes.

Comment: please add your filter form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using api router for this, there is api or v2 as prefix for api routes depending on version.
Web routes does not have prefix by default, but api routes does.
Error 404 is btw "not found" error. :D

So try api/inmuebles/buscar

Comment: something was wrong in my route, I made sure that information was coming to the function and then it work!